# Longest Repeated Substring

Tags: string-manipulation, sequence

Is there a solution in *Mathematica* to the problem of finding the longest substring of a sequence that occurs at least twice.For example `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3}` has the solution `{2,3}` or `"ABCDEDEFDEFA"` has the solution `"DEF"`.

Answer (score 3):

Brute force:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3} /. {___, Longest[n__], ___, n__, ___} :> {n}
```

> {1,2}

```
Characters["ABCDEDEFDEFA"] /. {___, Longest[n__], ___, n__, ___} :> StringJoin[n]
```

> "DEF"